# Swig: syntax error when wrapping global static constants

Tags: python, c++, swig

When I try to wrap the following code:

```
enum VehicleSide {
    LEFT = 0,  ///< left side of vehicle is always 0
    RIGHT = 1  ///< right side of vehicle is always 1
};

/// Class to encode the ID of a vehicle wheel.
/// By convention, wheels are counted front to rear and left to right. In other
/// words, for a vehicle with 2 axles, the order is: front-left, front-right,
/// rear-left, rear-right.
class WheelID {
  public:
    WheelID(int id) : m_id(id), m_axle(id / 2), m_side(VehicleSide(id % 2)) {}
    WheelID(int axle, VehicleSide side) : m_id(2 * axle + side), m_axle(axle), m_side(side) {}

    /// Return the wheel ID.
    int id() const { return m_id; }

    /// Return the axle index for this wheel ID.
    /// Axles are counted from the front of the vehicle.
    int axle() const { return m_axle; }

    /// Return the side for this wheel ID.
    /// By convention, left is 0 and right is 1.
    VehicleSide side() const { return m_side; }

  private:
    int m_id;            ///< wheel ID
    int m_axle;          ///< axle index (counted from the front)
    VehicleSide m_side;  ///< vehicle side (LEFT: 0, RIGHT: 1)
};

/// Global constant wheel IDs for the common topology of a 2-axle vehicle.
static const WheelID FRONT_LEFT(0, LEFT);
static const WheelID FRONT_RIGHT(0, RIGHT);
static const WheelID REAR_LEFT(1, LEFT);
static const WheelID REAR_RIGHT(1, RIGHT);
```

I get "syntax error in input" at **static const WheelID FRONT_LEFT(0, LEFT);**. 
On the interface file I'm just using %include on the corresponding header. 
I have no clue of what is causing the error, so any help is appreciated, but I would prefer not to edit the header.
Thanks

EDIT:
removing the *static* keyword won't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing your SWIG .i file would help, but the cause is likely that you've put instances of your class in the header file.  I see that you don't want to edit the header, but the .h file should `extern` the class instances and the definition should be in the .cpp file; otherwise, you'll have multiple separate instances of your global variables if the file is included in two different .cpp files.  Also, SWIG doesn't understand it as is so you've really no choice...

Working example:

**test.h**

```
enum VehicleSide {
    LEFT = 0,  ///< left side of vehicle is always 0
    RIGHT = 1  ///< right side of vehicle is always 1
};

/// Class to encode the ID of a vehicle wheel.
/// By convention, wheels are counted front to rear and left to right. In other
/// words, for a vehicle with 2 axles, the order is: front-left, front-right,
/// rear-left, rear-right.
class WheelID {
  public:
    WheelID(int id) : m_id(id), m_axle(id / 2), m_side(VehicleSide(id % 2)) {}
    WheelID(int axle, VehicleSide side) : m_id(2 * axle + side), m_axle(axle), m_side(side) {}

    /// Return the wheel ID.
    int id() const { return m_id; }

    /// Return the axle index for this wheel ID.
    /// Axles are counted from the front of the vehicle.
    int axle() const { return m_axle; }

    /// Return the side for this wheel ID.
    /// By convention, left is 0 and right is 1.
    VehicleSide side() const { return m_side; }

  private:
    int m_id;            ///< wheel ID
    int m_axle;          ///< axle index (counted from the front)
    VehicleSide m_side;  ///< vehicle side (LEFT: 0, RIGHT: 1)
};

// Instances of these global variables must be outside the header.
// What if the header was included in two files?
extern const WheelID FRONT_LEFT;
extern const WheelID FRONT_RIGHT;
extern const WheelID REAR_LEFT;
extern const WheelID REAR_RIGHT;
```

**test.i**

```
%module test

%{ // Section included verbatim in the generated wrapper source.

#include "test.h"

// One-time instances of the class.  In this case, directly
// added to the wrapper, but it could be in a separate .cpp file
// or .lib and linked to the final extension.
const WheelID FRONT_LEFT(0, LEFT);
const WheelID FRONT_RIGHT(0, RIGHT);
const WheelID REAR_LEFT(1, LEFT);
const WheelID REAR_RIGHT(1, RIGHT);

%}

// Generate wrappers for test.h contents
%include "test.h"
```

Demo:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.REAR_RIGHT.id()
3
```

Comment: Since those const are used in many part of the project I decided to define them in a .cpp file as you suggested. Now everything works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: @UncleBen You're welcome and welcome to SO! If this answers your question, please consider accepting it with the check control on the left.  Express thanks with upvotes as well :^)